# Setting up the JIRA in Leverice

Tags: jira

I saw some folks have Jira integration in Leverice, but I do not see how to create a Jira channel/branch anywhere in my Leverice application. Anyone know where to start so I can set this up too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sure.  First, to set this up you must have admin rights in your company/team’s Jira account.

The Jira channel can only be set up as a top-level channel and only in a Team.

On a Team that you have set up in Leverice (e.g. DevTeam) select New > Jira

A pop-up box with several fields will appear. These fields are as follows: Display Name, Project key, Site name, Atlassian id (email), Jira api token

Display Name: this can be anything you choose, for example you can call it Acme Dev

Project key: this must be the root acronym of all your existing Jira items. For example if your Jira items are ACME-1454, ACME-2595, etc. then your project key should be entered as ACME

Site name: this must be the root url of your Jira space, for example https://acmecompany.atlassian.net

Atlassian id (email): this must be the email address you use to login to Jira with admin rights

Jira api token: to obtain this token go to your Jira website, click on your Profile avatar in the bottom left corner, click on “Profile”, then click “Manage your account”. Next, select “Security” and scroll down to “Create and manage API tokens”. Click on it, create a token, and copy and paste it back into the Leverice pop-up box.

Finally, click “Create” in the Leverice pop-up box.